# Issue with media screen

Tags: css, content-management-system, screen, media

I have to build a website in a CMS named kwik (KwikCMS).

Now i have already made this whole site but i have to add a couple of media screens for several displays. I have tested all of this code in the F12 inspector and it should all fix it but for some reason it doesnt take my CSS.

I have tried it with and without !important already but i have no clue how to fix this.

This is my CSS code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px){

.site-scope .header-container .site-header .headerBlauw {
margin-left: -14.2% !important;
width: 102.5% !important;
}


.col-sm-12.module-wrapper.cms-preset-dropdown-shown{
height: 202px;
}

.row.site-header.header-slider {
padding: 0;
margin-left: -22px;
width: 1454px;
}

.site-scope .col-sm-12.module-datacontainer.module-align-left.module-container {
padding: 0 !important;
}

.site-scope .header-container .site-header .headerBlauw {
margin-left: -14.4% !important;
width: 96.6% !important;
}

.site-scope .header-container .site-header .module-menu {
margin-left: -24% !important;
}

.site-scope .col-sm-12.module-datacontainer.module-align-left.module-container {
padding: 0 !important;         
margin-top: -23px !important;
}

.row.monteurs.row-container.sortable {
margin-left: -76px !important;
}

.row.blokken.row-container.sortable {
margin-left: -190px !important;
left: 69px !important;
text-align: center !important;
}

}
```

Comment: Ok I will make a very wild guess. You are using max-width. It will change the css of the classes if the screen is 1440px and below.. But if you want it to display above 1440px use min-width.. and I think that is the case here..

Comment: After copy-pasting the code in a CSS Validator I got an unknown symbol in line 33 (also saw it in Sublime) : .site-scope .col-sm-12.module-datacontainer.module-align-left.module-container {
padding: 0 !important;         
margin-top: -23px !important;
}

Comment: @AntonZlatkov An unknown symbol?? where?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Does not work either, i also tried it without a max or min, just width: 1440px, does not work either

Comment: @JornBarkhof - "padding: 0 !important;         " in the ".site-scope .col-sm-12.module-datacontainer.module-align-left.module-container" selector. The unknown symbol looks like [?] when I open it in Sublime. I see it right after the "important;" - you will find some empty spaces and one of them is not empty but that symbol... Hope this helps

Comment: @AntonZlatkov I have deleted the spaces everywhere, i dont know how that happend but anyways, it still doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.headerBlauw` is included twice in your css, it may be not working as you want. Clarify which part of your code is not working as you want and how exactly do you include that css in your website

Comment: I see, the problem is the whole css that has to be applied with the media screen, none of it works, It just doesnt read the media screen for some reason

Comment: @JornBarkhof, try adding something like minimal width `@media screen and (min-width:1200px) and (max-width: 1400px)`. Check out if it works or not within that range, if not - update your question with link to your project pls

Answer (score 1):

```
> @media (max-width: 1440px){}
```

try to change your media in this code

Comment: may i see your html code? i want to see if you put this code

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I can't see the HTML code, its made in kwikcms. Or do you mean inspect it on the site?